# bashのtimeoutコマンドをshellスクリプトから実行すると終了ステータスが正しく取得できない

Tags: linux, bash

```
timeout 5 sleep 10 | tee -a LOG_FILE1 LOG_FILE2
RET=$?
echo "$RET"
```

上記のようにtimeoutコマンドを使用して終了ステータスの値によって処理を分岐させる実装していますが、
直でコマンドを実行した終了ステータスと
shellスクリプト内でコマンドを実行した際で終了ステータスが異なる為、
期待した動作になりません。
直でコマンドを実行した終了ステータス：124
shellスクリプト内でコマンドを実行した終了ステータス：0

どうすればshellスクリプト内でコマンドを実行した際に終了ステータスを正しく取得できるのでしょうか？

Comment: `timeout 5 ...` の前に `set -o pipefail` を追加してみて下さい。

Comment: set -o pipefail timeout 5 sleep 10 | tee -a LOG_FILE1 LOG_FILE2 として実行してみましたが、なにも表示されなくなりましたが、 metropolisさんの期待する結果はどのようなものだったのでしょうか？

Comment: こちら、bash 4.4.19 を使用していますが、`set -o pipefail` を追加して実行しますと `124` が表示されます。これは `timeout(1)` に記載されている、`If the command times out, and --preserve-status is  not  set,  then  exit with status 124.` の通りの結果です。

Comment: 今気が付きましたが、`set -o pipefail` は単独行にして下さい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

パイプの後半に`tee`コマンドを使用していますが、teeコマンドを挟むと終了ステータスを意図した通り拾えないケースがあるようです。

シェルスクリプトの中では終了ステータスを`$?`でチェックしていますが、代わりに`${PIPESTATUS}`を参照してみてください。

```
#/bin/bash
timeout 5 sleep 10 | tee -a LOG_FILE1 LOG_FILE2
RET=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
echo "$RET"
```

参考:
[teeでリターンコード拾えない問題 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/kugyu10/items/cee6a461c3bab063c947)

---

なお、質問の例で実行しているコマンドで気になるのは、タイムアウトした場合プロンプトに表示される`Terminated`の文字は**標準エラー**に対してです。一方、`sleep`コマンド自体は画面に何も出力しないので、パイプ(リダイレクト)の前半の結果に関わらず`tee`コマンドには何も文字列が渡らない気がします。

`tee`コマンドの必要性がいまいち読み取れませんが、参考リンク先にもあるようにエラー出力もリダイレクト時にハンドリングする方法なども別解として考えられます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
${PIPESTATUS[0]}を取得する事で期待通りのステータスを取得する事ができました。
${PIPESTATUS[0]}でtimeoutコマンドの終了ステータスが
${PIPESTATUS[1]}でteeコマンドの終了ステータスが取得できる事がわかりました。
今回はパイプで実行された最後のteeコマンドの終了ステータスを拾ってしまっていた為、発生していた事象でした。